# Requests to IIS (MVC4 app) waits 10 seconds inside pipeline (in ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0) before gets to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7.5

Enviroment: IIS 7.5. .NET 4.5.1. WINDOWS 2008 R2 SP1 Integrated Mode

I have an MVC application working in enviroment as above. Processing of some of my requests takes about 15 seconds. It has nothing to do with controller's action activities or view rendering. It happens also for actions returning view with one constant string or for JSON result actions. 
 In controller action's log I can see that the request begins it's execution about 10 second later than I can see it in fiddler on the browser side.
I've analyzed the request with Failed Requests Tracing and it turns out that the request gets stuck somewhere in the guts of IIS. This is the only request this time, there is a lot of free memory and processor time.
It turns out that the event that consumes about 10 seconds is always the event that uses ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 . Then the next event appears about 10 seconds later.

The common thing for these failerd request is tha they are issued as AJAX requests, but at the time they are processed there are no other open requests so concurency is not the issue.

What could be a reason for such delays?

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
<EventID>0</EventID>
<Version>1</Version>
<Level>4</Level>
<Opcode>43</Opcode>
<Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-03-28T15:44:19.663Z"/>
<Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0703-0080000000FC}"/>
<Execution ProcessID="9308" ThreadID="3504"/>
<Computer>COMP1</Computer>
</System>
<EventData>
<Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0703-0080000000FC}</Data>
<Data Name="OldHandlerName"></Data>
<Data Name="NewHandlerName">ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0</Data>
<Data Name="NewHandlerModules">ManagedPipelineHandler</Data>
<Data Name="NewHandlerScriptProcessor"></Data>
<Data Name="NewHandlerType">System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler</Data>
</EventData>
<RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
<Opcode>HANDLER_CHANGED</Opcode>
</RenderingInfo>
<ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
<EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
</ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
<EventID>0</EventID>
<Version>1</Version>
<Level>5</Level>
<Opcode>1</Opcode>
<Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-03-28T15:44:28.977Z"/>
<Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0703-0080000000FC}"/>
<Execution ProcessID="9308" ThreadID="3504"/>
<Computer>COMP1</Computer>
</System>
<EventData>
<Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0703-0080000000FC}</Data>
<Data Name="ModuleName">HttpCacheModule</Data>
<Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
<Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
</EventData>
<RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
<Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
<Keywords>
<Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
</Keywords>
<freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
</RenderingInfo>
<ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
<EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
</ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
```

Comment: After nine days of struggling it turned out that the problem was so trivial....


Some of my controllers from time to time were communicating with other program interfacing with other systems. This program was placed in the bin direcrory of my IIS application. Unfortunately this program was also writing a log file ... to the subdirectory of bin installation. It was probably notyfying IIS that some change in bin has occured and csc.exe was run to recomplile changes.

So the lesson is: AVOID WRITTING ANY LOGS IN THE BIN DIRECTORY OF YOUR IIS APPLICATION !!!

Answer (score 0):

We ran into a similar issue with an Angular SPA using ASP.NET API. On the first API call of the day, it was taking more than 20 seconds to return the result. We've done all suggested solutions of turning off IIS idle timeout, pre-compiling the .NET app, setting app the SPA and API on the same website to remove avoid the overhead of pre-flight requests, and none of those helped. We also found out that at random times, an API call takes more 20 seconds to return. We created a scheduled tasks to do an API call to keep the API active and we still get the intermittent delay. We turned ON Failed Request Tracing and what we found was the bulk of the delay was in HANDLER_CHANGED event.
[Failed Request Trace showing delay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6SSR.png)
After several days of searching for a solution and trying out suggestions, we came across this page and the solution. We also had some background processes that writes log files within the bin folder which was causing IIS to recompile and reload the application, hence causing the delay. Thanks Piotr for the info.